# eslint configuration package dependency error in project using cra

Tags: npm, eslint, create-react-app

I created a project using react and typescript using cra(create-react-app).

Afterwards, to apply eslint, I installed related packages as follows, but I keep getting dependency errors.

```
npm install eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin eslint-plugin-react 
eslint-plugin-react-hooks eslint-plugin-import --save-dev
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: bbb@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-react-app   
npm ERR!     eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest        
npm ERR!     eslint-plugin-jest@"^25.3.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app 
npm ERR!       eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" 
from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/parser@6.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^6.0.0 
|| ^6.0.0-alpha" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@6.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or 
retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-25T13_02_17_197Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-25T13_02_17_197Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried many things to solve the problem, but I couldn't find a fundamental solution.

I will attach the package.json file in the current project.

```
{
  "name": "bbb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.46",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you could leave a comment if you know about this issue.